# Visual Studio 2017 15.7 Preview 2 Hangs While Opening Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've been using `Visual Studio 2017 15.7 Preview 2` since it was released -- and `Preview 1` prior to that. My experience has been pretty good with it.

All of a sudden today, I just can't get into my project any more. When I click the solution open, I get the "Preparing Solution" message and it just hangs there.
[image]

If I try clicking anything in Visual Studio, I get the following message but it doesn't really solve anything.
[image]

Anyone else is having this issue? Any idea how to fix it? I just can't work on my project because of this issue.

P.S. I've been using the preview version because I wanted to work in `ASP.NET Core 2.1` which requires the preview version of `Visual Studio 2017`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here. In my case, deleting the `.vs` folder fixed the issue.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24938/vs2017-not-responding-when-opening-a-solution.html

Comment: It has worked for me in the past as well but it's not this time around :(